# Give an example of an ideal I such that $ht(P) < \mu(I)$ for every minimal prime P of I, where $\mu$ is the number of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Give an example of an ideal I such that $height(P) < \mu(I)$ for every minimal prime P of I, where $\mu$ is the number of generators.
And an example of an ideal I such that $height(P) = \mu(I)$ for every minimal prime P of I, but I
is not prime;

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any results you've learned that could be useful for this?

Comment: For the first case I thought of the following ideal: $I=(xz-y^2,x^3-yz,z^2-x^2y)$ which has 3 generators and I have already seen in some examples that it has height 2. So it would be enough take P as I itself. Am I thinking correctly?